# How to display dialogboxparam dialog through the Messagebox ButtonClick?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

i have using C++ win32 API.

i already craeate a dialogbox within a dialogbox using dailogboxparam function in bb class...

```
INT_PTR bb::DialogProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
 {
//some case and...

case IDC_OK:
DialogBoxParam(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG),_hwnd,myfunctionDlgProc,lp);
break;
}

int CALLBACK bb::myfunctionDlgProc(HWND hDlg,UINT msg,WPARAM  wp, LPARAM lParam)
{

//some code...
}
```

when i press the OK button in dialogbox...it shows myfunctionDlgProc Dialogbox...

Now,i want the same thing in my other aa class,now i am using messagebox..it have 2 buttons OK and Cancel...

if when i press messagebox ok button,i want to show the myfunctionDlgProc Dialogbox...

```
    int retun;

        retun = MessageBox(hDlg,(LPCWSTR)"",TEXT("Logon Message"), MB_OKCANCEL| MB_ICONWARNING);

        if(retun=1)
       {
DialogBoxParam(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG),_hwnd,myfunctionDlgProc ,lp);
        }
```

i try it...but how to i pass the `lp` value in this code...

`DialogBoxParam(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG),_hwnd,myfunctionDlgProc,lp);`

Did u get my issue?

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please explain what `lp` is supposed to be.

Comment: @ Raymond:i didnt know,how to say that..see the below link..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645465(v=vs.85).aspx    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That link does not explain what `myfunctionDlgProc` wants `lp` to be.

Comment: @ Raymond:Without `lp`,how u can use the dialogboxparam function?

Comment: If `myfunctionDlgProc` doesn't use the `lp`, then why not just use the `DialogBox` function, or equivalently just pass zero. I think you don't understand what the `lp` parameter is for.

Comment: I got it...just i am using LPARAM lp; in that code,its works fine...thank u.