# How to hide my current window,when i click the ok button using C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

i am using C++ win32  API...

i have a window(dialogbox),that windows has some buttons...

if,i enter one of the OK button,one messagebox will appear...

at that time,i want to hide the background window(Dialogbox)...

How to i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @ Rudolfs:thank u..it works fine.can u give suggestion for the below issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171488/how-to-display-dialogboxparam-dialog-through-the-messagebox-buttonclick

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass SW_HIDE to your dialog

Comment: @ ISTB :thank u,it works fine...can u give suggestion for the below issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171488/how-to-display-dialogboxparam-dialog-through-the-messagebox-buttonclick